# Create root volume from snapshot in CloudFormation and attach to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, yaml, aws-cloudformation

is there a way to create a volume based on an existing snapshot and then attach that volume to an EC2 instance in a CloudFormation template?

This is a snippet of my current template right now that creates a new volume at each launch.

```
Resources:
  EC2Example:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        services:
          sysvint:
            codedeploy-agent:
              enabled: 'true'
              ensureRunning: 'true'
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref ImageId
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      KeyName: !Ref SSHKeyName
      IamInstanceProfile: "EC2CodeDeploy"
      NetworkInterfaces: 
        - AssociatePublicIpAddress: "true"
          DeviceIndex: "0"
          GroupSet: 
            - Ref: "SecurityGroupIds"
          SubnetId: 
            Ref: "PrivateSubnet"
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        -
          DeviceName: /dev/sda1
          Ebs:
            VolumeType: io1
            Iops: !Ref IOPS
            DeleteOnTermination: false
            VolumeSize: !Ref VolumeSize
```

I've tried VolumeAttachment but im getting the error that "Invalid value '/dev/sda1' for unixDevice. Attachment point /dev/sda1 is already in use"

```
  NewVolume:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Volume
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Ref AvailabilityZone
      SnapshotId: 'MySnapshotID'
      Tags:
        - Key: MISPVol
          Value: MISPVol

  MountPoint:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment
    Properties:
      InstanceId: !Ref EC2Example
      VolumeId: !Ref NewVolume
      Device: /dev/sda1
```

Comment: If you are wanting this for the root volume, you want to create an AMI from your snapshot.   I would make sure you need the io1 drive, those are very costly compared the the same amount of IOPs you can get from gp3. io1/2 is often only needed for it's lower latency.

Comment: I think I misunderstood. If you want a persistent volume between instance refreshes, you need to define the volume outside of the instance definition and use `AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment`

Comment: @jordanm, thanks for the reply, I've edited my attempt in the post

Comment: You can't attach the root volume in this way, if it's for the root volume, you need to create an AMI. I would advise against trying to store persistent data on the root volume.